# C++ Having issues reusing the same object to hold a different value

Tags: c++, arrays, object, crash

Recently, I've been trying to understand why this error occurs:

```
BigNum num = 50;
num = 2;
```

When I create a BigNum with a value of 50, then try to input a value of 2 into it later, my program crashes.

These are the two constructors I use:

```
    // constructor where operand is a long
BigNum::BigNum(long num) {
    negative = num < 0;
    unsigned long absNum = abs(num);
    length = numberOfDigits(absNum);
    data = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; absNum != 0; i++) {
        data[i] = absNum % 10;
        absNum /= 10;
    }
}

// copy constructor
BigNum::BigNum(BigNum const& orig) {
    int arrSize = orig.length;
    data = new char[arrSize];
    copy(orig.data, orig.data + arrSize, data);
    negative = orig.negative;
    length = orig.length;
}

// destructor
BigNum::~BigNum() {
    delete[] data;
}
```

The elements in the object are:

```
bool negative;
int length;
char *data;
```

of which data holds digits for the BigNum.

However, the use of both of these constructors and destructor does not allow me to refactor the value of the object.

Could anyone shed some light on why this would be happening?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles. I suggest you write an assignment operator that takes an `int` argument.

Comment: 'sizeof(orig.data)' :  sizeof(pointer)

Comment: You should `delete[] data` in the copy constructor to free the old array, or you have a memory leak. (even if this is not why your code is crashing)

Comment: Putting `delete[] data` in the copy constructor makes my program crash

Comment: The most likely answer is that numberOfDigits() is wrong, and, upon return, the allocated array is too short, and the subsequent code ends up stomping on memory. Additionally, "num=2" invokes the assignment operator, not a constructor, whose code you've neglected to post; that could be another place for the bug to exist.